# SHFileOperation works but prints error messages

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2017, c++14, shfileoperation

I'm using Shell API to copy a folder with files.

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT sf = {0};
sf.wFunc = FO_COPY;
sf.hwnd = 0;
sf.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_SILENT | FOF_NO_UI;
sf.pFrom = "C:\\Users\\Sergi0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\untar.temp\\000\0";
sf.pTo = "F:\\\0";

// both pFrom and pTo are double NULL terminated, I have rechecked it

int err = SHFileOperation(&sf);
```

Everything works fine, folder is copied to the drive F:
The problem is that messages

```
internal\sdk\inc\wil\filesystem.h(820)\windows.storage.dll!7684045C: (caller: 7676413A) ReturnHr(2) tid(660) 80070057 Incorrect parameter.
...
internal\sdk\inc\wil\filesystem.h(820)\windows.storage.dll!7684045C: (caller: 7676413A) ReturnHr(101) tid(660) 80070057 Incorrect parameter.
```

are printed in Visual Studio debug console. There are 100 files inside folder 000 and 100 messages were printed.

Should I be worried about these? I'm using VS 2017 on Windows 10.

**UPDATE**
I have tried with another device, I see the same errors in both VS2017 and VS2008. But, there are no such errors with generic flash drive. So it seems it has something to do with mass storage implementation on the devices I use.
I didn't find file filesystem.h anywhere in SDK.

Comment: You aren't double null terminating your strings. They are only single null-terminated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am, they are double terminated.

Comment: without double termination the call fails immideately

Comment: side note: in C++ `{0}` only zeros the first field, if you intend to do the whole structure you should just use `{}` which will zero the entire structure.

Comment: I've seen that exception pop up elsewhere when a drive attached to the system was faulty. No idea if that applies here but can you try a different source/destination?

Comment: With the edit to the question you are double null terminating. But I now wonder what your code really is.

Comment: @Mgetz False. Aggregate initialization value-initializes all members for which initializers were not explicitly provided, which for primitive types is equivalent to zero-initialization. Bottom line is, `SHFILEOPSTRUCT sf = {0};` is perfectly fine and sets all members of the structure to zero or NULL as needed.

Comment: @Mgetz Just wanted to write the same as Igor. Here is the [relevant part of the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization): _"If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members are value-initialized."_ [Value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) in this case means set-to-zero.

Comment: if you attach debugger to explorer - you can view many such debug output messages. this is win 10 "feature"

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I highly suggest you look at the output assembly from MSVC. You'll facepalm pretty hard.

Comment: @Mgetz - i look assembly of `SHFILEOPSTRUCT sf = {0};` - it zeroinit all `sf`

Comment: @Mgetz [Looks perfectly OK](https://godbolt.org/g/Fj4yJC) from where I sit.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik [mine looks better because it's not doing two independent stores](https://godbolt.org/g/T2vMFx)

Comment: @Mgetz That may be. Nevertheless, your claim that `SHFILEOPSTRUCT sf = {0};` only zero-initializes the first members and leaves the rest uninitialized is false.

Comment: @Mgetz - `/O3` option have not sense for CL - use `/O2` or `/Ox` for full  optimization. anyway result with `S s = {};` and `S s = {0};` both corect

Comment: Do you get the same messages when running the code on a clean install of Windows? You can use [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to see those messages, so you don't have to install Visual Studio. It would also be helpful if you mentioned, what types of volumes C: and F: are (local drives, removable drives, network drives).

Comment: @Basic I'll try another devices, but the error messages are about call parameters validation, so I don't suspect the device.

Comment: @IInspectable Nope, I can't get a clean install at the moment. C: is a local windows drive, F is removable. I'll try a couple of difference devices.

Comment: @Basic it may have bee the device after all (I have update the original post). It isn't faulty, but something is definitely not right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to worry about these messages. The copy engine is trying to get information about the destination directory (`F:\`) but it turns out that it's not a directory; it's a drive. The error is returned ("Silly copy engine, that's not a directory."), the copy engine says "Sorry," and everything proceeds normally.

Sorry for creating unnecessary alarm.

Comment: Note, Raymond or I will file a bug on this and try to get it fixed. thanks for the report.

Comment: Raymond Chen apologized to me and he made it all better

Comment: @ChrisGuzak Thanks. Please let me know if that turns out as a possible problem on the device side after all.

Comment: @Sergi0 Nope, it's completely on us. I dug in a little deeper. We are trying to get some information from a non-NTFS volume (your flash drive is probably FAT32), and the call fails, and due to overzealous error reporting, we print a message even though the failure is benign.

Comment: @RaymondChen oh, now I see the difference with the USB stick. device is FAT16, and USB stick is NTFS.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I be worried about these?

If the files are being copied correctly, and `SHFileOperation()` is not reporting an error back to your code, then no, do not worry about it.  The debug messages are internal to the API and the "incorrect parameter" errors are being handled internally by the API.

On the other hand, `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` does have an `fAnyOperationsAborted` field that will be set to `TRUE` if any of the individual files fails to copy.  `SHFileOperation()` itself may be successful overall, but individual files may have failed, so your code should check for that condition.

Comment: everything OK, the removable drive is OK, i have no problems while deleting or copying files there from explorer or total commander. fAnyOperationsAborted  is always zero. I'm worried because this is the first version of app built on VS2017. I have used VS2008 before and never saw any of those.

Comment: All files are copied, the number of messages corresponds to the number of files.

Comment: @Sergi0 like I said, don't worry about it (you can't do anything about it anyway). If you don't like seeing the debug messages, file a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: I have updated the question, I'm more worried now :)

Comment: @Sergi0 my guess is the API issues a command that the device doesn't like/support, so the API either skips the command or tries something else. Again, no big deal, it is just of the implementation and is handled internally.